# How can I show RecyclerView and CardView layouts in an activity with a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-fragmentactivity

### This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Mucitler"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

### This is my custom_recycler_view_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
    card:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card:cardElevation="2dp"
    card:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivImageOfCity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/android_image"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNameOfCity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="#55000000"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Sehir Adı"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageFrame"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCountryOfCity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Austalia"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPopulationOfCity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="1 M population"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**How can I show RecyclerView and CardView layouts in an activity with a fragment? I also have MainActivity and City Model codes. Please help me, thanks.**

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. But, looking at it, I think you want to use `CardView` because of the elevation it has as the holder of the items on your `RecycleView` right?

Comment: I have two layouts that are custom recyclerview and main and I am importing data from City class to RecyclerView object. In addition I am using NavigationDrawer and when I click the city section on the NavDrawer I want to bring City Fragment to Acitivy. Get it? for more please view: https://github.com/Viveka/AndroidEgitimi/tree/master/RecycleCardAndRefreshLayoutDenemesi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you have to initialize recyclerview in your fragment activity
for displaying cardview you have to create RecyclerViewAdapter class and in that class you have to put the data which you want to show in cardview.
after that simply call RecyclerViewAdapter in your fragment.